# jQuery Datatables rendering

Tags: jquery, datatables, render

In my table I have two fields that are 0 or 1. One of "active" and one is "operative".

So I added this code

```
"columnDefs": [ {

        "targets": 3,
        "data": "active",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green"></i>';}
          else
            { return '<i class="fas fa-times" style="color:red"></i>';}
        },

        
        "targets": 4,
        "data": "operative",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green"></i>';}
          else
            { return "";}
        }

  } ]
```

which should work OK. The column numbers are correct, but the table only render colum 4. If I remove the definition for column 4 it renders column  3 correctly.

Here is a screenshot of the bit in question:

[image]

Here is the full definition of the table

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(function () {
 var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
"iDisplayLength": 25,
"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50,100,200, -1], [10, 25, 50,100,200, "All"] ],
    columnDefs: [
    {
        targets: -1,
        className: 'dt-right'
    }],
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax:"{{ route('AllUsersData') }}",
    columns: [
        
        {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'company',name: 'company'},
        {data: 'active', name:'active'},
        {data: 'operative', name: 'operative'},
        {data: 'superAdmin', name:'superAdmin'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
    ],

     "columnDefs": [ {

        "targets": 3,
        "data": "active",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green"></i>';}
          else
            { return '<i class="fas fa-times" style="color:red"></i>';}
        },

        
        "targets": 4,
        "data": "operative",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green"></i>';}
          else
            { return "";}
        },

         "targets": 5,
        "data": "superAdmin",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green"></i>';}
          else
            { return "";}
        }


  } ]

    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is a sample of the returned data from the ajax call:

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] the question, to show (1) some sample source JSON(?) data, (2) the DataTable definition, and (3) the HTML table code?

Comment: I have added the data as requested

Comment: Sorry I should have stated I added a column. Always it is the last one that renders correctly

Comment: Thanks for the updates. For future reference, it is always better to provide the actual data (the original JSON in this case) as formatted text, rather than (or maybe as well as) a screenshot of the data. It is easier to copy and test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

1 - You have 2 separate `columnDefs` sections - these should be merged into one - otherwise the first one, containing `className: 'dt-right'`, will be ignored.

2 - The second larger `columnDefs` section is missing some curly braces.  You have an overall structure like this:

```
"columnDefs": [...]
```

Within that, each `targets` section needs to be contained in its own `{...}` object:

```
    "columnDefs": [
      {
        targets: -1,
        className: 'dt-right'
      },     
      {
        "targets": 3,
        "data": "active",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green">x</i>';}
          else
            { return '<i class="fas fa-times" style="color:red">y</i>';}
        }
      },
      {
        "targets": 4,
        "data": "operative",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green">q</i>';}
          else
            { return "p";}
        }
      },
      {
        "targets": 5,
        "data": "superAdmin",
        "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
          if (data == 1)
            {return '<i class="fas fa-check" style="color:green">w</i>';}
          else
            { return "s";}
        }
      } 
    ]
```

3 - I would be careful using statements such as `if(data == 1)`. In this case, the value of data is a string for example, `"1"` or `"0"`. So you are effectively saying `if("1" == 1)`. This will evaluate to `true`...

...but it would be safer to use `if(data === "1")` - where the triple-equals checks not only the value but also the data type.

I think that should resolve your issues - but there may be additional problems hiding behind these ones. If so, those may need a follow-up question.

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not see the extra colDefs. It's amazing how you can look at code and miss something. I have taken on board you if (data === "1") and now all is well. Thanks again!