# Set the value of a variable from a value found in a table cell within an Ajax call using jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

How can I set the value of a variable (or to be more specific - a button attribute in each row) from a value found in another cell on the same row? The data in this example is being passed from an MVC controller to an Ajax success function:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
            cache: false,
            retrieve: true,
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            defaultContent: true,
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });
        function successFunc(data) {
            var firstName; //I'll need to set this variable with the name found in each row and assign that value to each Edit button attribute.
            $("#tblMyTable").DataTable(
                {
                    "info": true,
                    "data": data.list,
                    "responsive": true,
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "retrieve": true,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': "ID", }, 
                        { 'data': "First_Name" }, //This is the value I need. How can I set the value of the variable firstName using this data so that each button contains the attribute data-name with the value of the name column found in the current row?
                        { 'data': "Last_Name" },
                        { 'data': 'Edit', defaultContent: '<button type="button" data-name="' + firstName + '" href="javascript:;">Edit</button>' }

                    ]
                });

        }
        function errorFunc() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can bind a `click` event callback to it. Upon click, gather the specific detail. Then use AJAX to send the detail.

Comment: You appear to have the value in `data.First_Name`, so why not just reference that property in the `data` object?  If that doesn't work, please `console.log(data)` and update your question with the results so we can understand the structure of the `data` object

Comment: Also check out this thread: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/52485/passing-value-to-custom-column-defaultcontent

Comment: @devlincarnate the data parameter contains an array of all rows and I'm needing to set the value of the button attribute for each row.

Comment: See [How to use render function get data from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529987/jquery-datatable-how-to-use-render-function-get-data-from-another-column) for an example which shows how to use a [render function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render). This gives you access to every field in the row.

Comment: Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096015/jquery-datatables-rendering) , which shows an example of how to access the row data using render.

Comment: Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction. I was able to find a solution by adding the render function within columnDefs and assigning the attribute by accessing the row.First_Name parameter - see the link from @devlincarnate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the render function within columnDefs worked for me. `columnDefs` should follow the `columns` option:

```
"columnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": [3],
        "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
            {
                return '<button type="button" data-name="' + row.First_Name + '" href="javascript:;">Edit</button>'
            }
        }
    }
]
```